# Official ld linker spec

Tags: c++, linker, specifications

I'm newbie in C++ and I want to understand how does linker work formally. I'm using `Linux Mint 16`. Is there exist `ld` linker official spec?

Comment: I didn't got what exactly you want to know but give a try to this article http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463

Comment: `man ld`. The non-facietious answer depends on how deep you want to go, try google, there are plenty of articles & papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get more idea about linker and shared libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876949/questions-about-shared-libraries) 
also [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) is man page for ld.so which is linker.

[Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463) is brief description about linker and loaders in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good book on the whole subject: "Linkers and Loaders" by John Levine. It describes the issues, various different implementations, object formats and a bunch of other interesting stuff.

See [Amazon Kindle Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008HNGAG0)